# Powershell - Trigger or suppress Where-Object clause based on boolean

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, pipeline, powershell-5.0

### What I'm trying to do

I have a configurable Powershell 5.1 script with the following variable:

```
[bool]$SourceFilter
```

Based on the value of this boolean, I may or may not trigger a Where-Object clause in the middle of a pipeline, which is filtering a large and complex Array of objects:

```
$objectArray <# | Where-Object {$_.Attributes.Value -NotLlike "*this*"} #> | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Attributes.Name}
```

**How do I encode the Where-Object clause to only trigger if $SourceFilter = $true?**

---

### What I've tried

I've tried encoding the clause as a variable and then using Invoke-Expression to rationalise it into the pipeline, but can't seem to get this working:

```
$script = '| Where-Object {$_.Attributes.pointsource -NotLike "*AF*"}'
$output = if($SourceFilter)
             {Invoke-Expression "$objectArray $script" | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Attributes.Name}}
          else
             {$objectArray | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Attributes.Name}}
```

This approach gives me an error which states that the $variable is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, script or program.

Comment: why do you expect the [horribly named] `$Variable` var to hold anything when you have not assigned anything to it?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - haha, I can assure you that it's a well named object containing ~50k elements. It's just built using a very specific Powershell module pretty much nobody would relate to outside of my industry, and so I thought it was best to keep it simple for the sake of asking the question.

Comment: that sort of thing is _important_ ... so you likely otta make it very clear where the $Var is coming from and roughly what will be in it. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

You can have a scriptblock variable set to either your condition or true.

```
$sb1 = {$true}
$sb2 = {$_ -like 'a*'}

echo hi | where $sb1
hi

echo hi | where $sb2
```

Comment: thanks js - I'd considered doing something like this, but the variable going into the pipeline has many thousands of objects to iterate through, and so I thought it'd be ideal to avoid piping it all through a redundant step if I didn't have to. Perhaps I'm just overcomplicating it and should just have two different versions of the pipeline code and use the boolean to trigger an if-else.

Comment: @SteveTaylor - the whole point of the `W-O` cmdlet is to filter things. i can't see any way to run a pipeline with a pre-filter. [*grin*]

Comment: Some cmdlets like get-wmiobject or get-childitem have a -filter option too which would be faster.